# Visual Studio PHP Tools not formatting code

Tags: php, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, formatting, php-extension

I'm writing php in Visual Studio using the PHP Tools extension. The code formatting of the PHP Tools doesn't seem to be working.

The formatting option is available in the options menu:
[image: Options menu php formatting code]

And I have tried linking the php-extension to the PHP Editor:
[image: Options menu link php extension]

But nothing seems to work. When I try right-clicking a php document and choose Formatting and Validation it goes straight to HTML (Web Forms).

The problem seems to lie with Visual Studio not recognizing php as a language. Anybody an idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend asking directly at https://community.devsense.com/ - seems like a bug, and maybe there is a quick fix for it. A screenshot of the context menu and the opened PHP document would help.